# jquery select the input inside immediate li

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
<li id="li-2014-08-04">
<input id="radio-2014-08-04" value="2014-08-04" type="radio" name="radio_date">4
</li>
```

I am trying to use jquery to select the input inside the li tag.
there are hundreds of elements the idea is to select the input and return if checked or not.

Comment: do you have a reference to the `li` element

Comment: yes they all have date based ids

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have unique IDs for li element, you can use:

```
var radbtn = $('#li-2014-08-04').find('input[type="radio"]');
```

to check whether button is check:

```
var radbtn_ischecked = $('#li-2014-08-04').find('input[type="radio"]').is(':checked');
```

Comment: the first one worked great    var radbtn = $(this).find('input[type="radio"]'); since the event is triggered with a click thanks Milind.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following selector...

```
var isChecked = $('#li-2014-08-04 input').prop('checked');
```

Here's a [JS Fiddler Example](http://jsfiddle.net/cpza00uj/)

However, can you expand a bit in your question. Why are you setting the `li` element ids with a date format? There could be much better ways to achieve whatever you're trying to do